# PageViewController with different page views in storyboard ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to create `UIPageViewController` and assign 4 different `UIViewControllers` for different content of pages? Do I need to connect them via `segue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to set a `UIPageViewController`s view controllers (of which there are only 2 at most at a time) in a storyboard. You can however design the interfaces of the content controllers in the storyboard. You don't need to connect them with segues, just give them a Storyboard ID, and then you can instantiate them in your `dataSource` using:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardID"];
```

For a demo check out the page based application template in Xcode, it does exactly this.